# How do I overcome the 256 character limit for VLOOKUP (Multiple cells in a column)

Tags: excel, vlookup

I'm collating cells from different sheets using

=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A1:A10, Sheet1!A1:A10, 1, FALSE)

The issue is that some cells have characters that have more than 256 characters.
I need to import the whole column of cells together to account for the addition of future rows.

Are there any workarounds to get the data to display?

Comment: `=Sheet1!A1:A10` would return the same results

Comment: Helper column with the left or right of the contents with the most useful identifying info?